# Removable Drive keeps getting dropped/ unmounted

Tags: mount, fstab, media, usb-drive

I plug in my 1tb removable Drive and Ubuntu mounts it. I start extracting my 45gb of 7z compressed photos and after a period of time appears to be about 10 minutes the drive unmounts and the extraction fails.

How can I stop the drive unmouting?

I have uninstalled laptop-mode-tools as I read a few posts that led to that conclusion however that did not help.

dmesg provides this output.

```
[  372.444377] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 31323601
[  372.444384] sd 4:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  372.444389] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] killing request
[  372.444396] sd 4:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  372.444411] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
[  372.444413] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[  372.444414] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  372.444416] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[  372.444417] Read(10): 28 00 0e ef af 6f 00 00 20 00
[  372.444424] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 250589039
[  372.444441] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 95
[  372.444450] sd 4:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  372.523846] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 96 using ehci-pci
[  387.602089] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
```

My fstab is very plain

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=6da37d02-881e-455f-8f1a-93db2ddc7f3c /boot           ext2    defaults     $
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I have added this to fstab to always mount it the same.

```
UUID=16D48A3ED48A205B /media/imation ntfs user,noauto,rw 0 0
```

dmesg | tail provides this.

```
sayth:~$ dmesg | tail
[  687.791103] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 31310276
[  687.791106] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 31310277
[  687.791109] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 31310278
[  687.791113] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 31310279
[  687.791165] sd 4:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  687.791170] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  687.942519] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[  703.020594] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  718.206700] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  718.382767] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
```

And fsck can't help, I am really out of ideas.

```
sayth:~$ fsck /dev/sdb1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck: fsck.ntfs: not found
fsck: error 2 while executing fsck.ntfs for /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: You will have to provide more details.

Comment: @psusi.       Yeah added some more and tried a few options but still no go

Comment: You got some broken hardware somewhere.  Try a different usb cable, and computer, and if that doesn't fix it then it's the drive/enclosure.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your drive is damaged:

```
[  372.444424] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 250589039
```

Here are some things to try:

1. Attach the drive to a Windows machine and run a checkdisk there. NTFS checks are probably better under Windows (this is an assumption).
2. Run `ntfsck`. On Debian systems, `/sbin/fsck.ntfs` is a symlink to `/bin/ntfsfix` but this does not seem to be the case on Ubuntu. So, you need to run `ntfsck` manually. This should already be installed but if not, install it with `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`. Then run

   ```
   sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
   ```
3. Use `smartctl` to show the S.M.A.R.T. status of your drive:

   ```
   sudo smartctl /dev/sdb
   ```

   This won't solve anything but might help debug the problem.

Comment: Thanks, it seems the drive has trouble indeed. I have all the data already backed up elsewhere so am going to fully reformat drive and see how that goes. .